# Need to remove (grey) background color When select event occurred in Material-ui Select Component

Tags: select, material-ui

**Code link**
Here Is the Code of the Select Componenet that i've been trying

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-leftpad-ugrlp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the background color transition in focus state? Add `disableRipple` prop to your `MenuItem` components:

```js
<MenuItem disableRipple value="nearby">
  Nearby
</MenuItem>
```